# Symfony add a parameter to route, this parameter is a encoded URI

Tags: symfony, routes

I have a route defined like this (controller has a prefix `/email`):

```
/**
 * Opens send dialog
 *
 * @Route("/compose/{redirect_to}", name="email_compose", defaults={"redirect_to" = "/"})
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 * @Template("EmailBundle:Email:compose.html.twig")
 */
```

I try to call this route via a javascript ajax POST, but even with a GET request I have routing errors:

http://example.com/app_dev.php/email/compose/%2Fapp_dev.php%2Fcurrent%2Fdetail%2F7

This throws a 404 error:

> The requested URL /app_dev.php/email/compose//app_dev.php/current/detail/7 was not found on this server

If I try a simpler call like this one, it works properly:

http://example.com/app_dev.php/email/compose/aaa

How can I pass a parameter in querystring that is an URI?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can by allowing slashes in the corresponding route, e.g. :

```
compose:
    pattern: /compose/{redirectTo}
    # [defaults]
    requirements:
        redirectTo: ".+"
```

The corresponding doc [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/slash_in_parameter.html).

But, because you are not trying to use an Ajax routing (in this case the custom route is mandatory), there is no reason to pass your target url as a route param.

(pass it as a query would be `/compose?redirecTo=[redirectTo]`

Also, as stated by @johnSmith (too fast!), you should use a `POST` request by require it like so in your route :

```
other:
    pattern: /compose
    # [defaults]
    requirements:
        methods: POST
```

Then, just retrieve the param like he said, and create your redirection.

Comment: The thing is, I prefer this param in querystring as route can be called via GET or POST, so in GET calls it will be easier to compose the route. I still get a 404 with this `@Route("/compose/{redirect_to}", name="email_compose", defaults={"redirect_to" = ""}, requirements={"redirect_to"=".+"})`

Comment: BTW, I'm doing an Ajax call

Comment: I think the double `//` in your route can be the cause of the problem (make the route restarted just after the hostname) . Try to remove the first `/` in your `redirectTo` and that should works with the requirements you added.

Comment: I'm not sure about what I said because the route is entirely interpreted as the error say. I'm not familiar with the `@Route` annotation, be sure that the requirements are correctly, maybe by looking in the doc.

Answer (score 2):

you should use POST as Method and add the redirect route to the formdata

sth liek this

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/path/to/file',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {redirectTo: '/current/detail/7'},
})
```

and in controller you parse this data like

```
$redirectTo=$this->getRequest()->get('redirectTo');
```

so you wont have any trouble

you would also not have any trouble if you urlEncode the redirectTo and append as GET parameter, e.g after `?` you could retrieve it then with the same code as above, but having an url  as fragment of a route doesnt make too much sense, but that may also be possible with allowing `/` to be a valid character in parameter

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/slash_in_parameter.html

Comment: I applied both solutions, POST and use of ? in querystring instead of routing  parameter